# How to stop asyncio tasks in TaskGroup after catching KeyboardInterrupt exception twice within a certain time frame?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.11

I have Python program that runs multiple asyncio tasks using [asyncio.TaskGroup](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-groups).

All of the tasks are waiting for some event to happen and I want them being cancelled when any of them completes.

I want that the program can also be closed by sending an interrupt signal (Ctrl+C in terminal), but to prevent it being closed accidentally, that should succeed only when it is sent two times within two seconds.

`try-except` blocks can be used around `asyncio.run` to catch `KeyboardInterrupt`, but that closes all the tasks and I would need to recreate them if interrupt happened only once and I want to continue the tasks.

I found a solution already that seems to work, but I am not 100% sure if it's the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to pass list to each task as a container where references to them can be kept. This way any of the tasks can stop all the other tasks after it completes.

By utilizing [asyncio.loop.add_signal_handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.add_signal_handler) and keeping track of when the last SIGINT was caught it is possible determine whether there were two interrupts within two seconds or not.

```py
import asyncio
from asyncio import Task
from random import random
from signal import SIGINT
from time import time


def cancel_all(tasks: list[Task]):
    for task in tasks:
        if task != asyncio.current_task() and not task.done():
            task.cancel()


def ask_exit(tasks: list[Task], last_sigint: list[float]):
    time_now = time()

    if time_now < last_sigint[0] + 2:
        cancel_all(tasks)
        return

    last_sigint[0] = time_now
    print("Are you sure you want to exit?")


async def some_task(tasks: list[Task]):
    await asyncio.sleep(5 + random() * 5)  # event to happen
    cancel_all(tasks)


async def run_tasks() -> None:
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as group:
        tasks: list[Task] = []
        tasks.append(group.create_task(some_task(tasks)))
        tasks.append(group.create_task(some_task(tasks)))

        last_sigint: list[float] = [0.0]

        asyncio.get_running_loop().add_signal_handler(
            SIGINT, ask_exit, tasks, last_sigint
        )

    asyncio.get_running_loop().remove_signal_handler(SIGINT)
    print("All tasks done.")


asyncio.run(run_tasks())
```